# how to use multi-processing pools in python that submit qsub jobs

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a method in python that need to be submitted to sge to process since there are a lot of data. Lets say I want to submit 1000 job a time

Here is my code:

```
list_argument = [{dict1}, {dict2}.... {dict99999999999}]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1000)
       output_data = pool.map(process_list, list_argument)
```

method in process_list:

```
process_list(process_dict):
    temp_json = process_dict['name'].json
    with open(temp_json, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(process_dict, outfile)
    
    cmd = ["qsub","-S", "/usr/bin/bash",
           "run_list_segment.sh",
           "run_list_segment.py", temp_json]
    logging.info("Running: %s", " ".join(cmd))
    try:
        run_command = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        run_command.check_returncode()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
        logging.error("Error: return code %s", str(error.returncode))
        logging.error("Output %s: ", str(error.stdout))
    
    pandas_csv = process_dict['name'].csv
    if os.path.isfile(pandas_csv):
        df = pandas.read_csv(pandas_csv, dtype={'CHROM': 'str'})
        #os.unlink(pandas_csv)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"{pandas_csv} wasn't created")
```

run_list_segment.py does something and return a pandas csv for it's name, and
run_list_segment.sh just do

```
python run_list_segment.py temp_json
```

This code works when my list_argument isn't that big (like under 5000), but when I am trying to do a big set, it start failing around 20000. and just complain that it can't find a pandas_csv file that should have been created. I think it's due to the number of job submitted were sitting on queue but the `pool` went to next set.

How do I fix this?

I tried `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` after declaring `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1000)` but then after first set, it just says
`ValueError: Pool not running`

Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you

Comment: There's confusion here.  You seem to have both a function and a dictionary called `process_list`.  Was that supposed to be `process_dict` inside the function?  If the function that creates the CSV is the same function that's reading it, then process congestion shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, so `process_list` is a method that takes `process_dict` as argument. `process_list` convert `process_dict` to json, perform qsub `run_list_argument` that will return a pandas csv, and read that csv and return a df

Comment: I edit the error on the script

Comment: and as for your question, the function that creates the CSV is the one getting qsub, so they aren't in same function

Comment: Did you mean `run_list_segment`?  How does that that code know what CSV file to create?  `qsub` just submits something to a queue and exits, right?  Just because `qsub` returns does not mean the task has actually run.  Given that, it seems quite likely that your code will often continue running before the file is created.  Perhaps you just need to wait for it in a loop.

Comment: yes, `run_list_segment .py` which getting called in `run_list_segment .sh` generats the CSV file. I have `-sync Yes` in the `run_list_segment.sh`, which should resolve the code to wait for qsub to finish before looking for pandas. But I am not sure if that's the correct way to do it. I also don't know how long to wait. It doesn't make sense that it works for 5000 dataset but not for 20000 dataset. Run time is same for both

Comment: It doesn't matter what `run_list_segment.sh` does.  It will not even have started by the time the `qsub` command returns.  You need to have a different strategy.  Maybe, suibmit all 20,000 jobs, then after you have submitted them all, go into another loop that waits for the CSV files and processes them.  THAT'S the way to do parallel processing.

Comment: isn't `qsub -sync yes` technically should wait for it? but I see what you are saying. Can I just add a statement like `while not os.path.exists(pandas_csv):
        time.sleep(5)` before reading the pandas_csv?

Comment: Yes, but you are not specifying `-sync yes` in your call to `qsub`.  Perhaps you need to add that to your `cmd` list.

Comment: hm... I thought having it in the shell script like `#$ -sync Yes` should be sufficient. Maybe I need to put that in cmd not in shell

Comment: OK, that might be a feature of `qsub` that I'm not aware of.